# How to set previous selected dates in times square calendar picker view from today?

Tags: android

I want to set previous dates on the calendar and I am using times square library calendarPickerView.....Dates are coming from server, and I want to highlight with red colour on the calendar.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: CalendarPickerView val_view = promptView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
        Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextYear.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

Date today = new Date();
       

        val_view.init(today, nextYear.getTime())
                .inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.SINGLE);

Comment: Thanks, its get resolved.